# Chrome cuts off div when scaled down, despite overflow:auto and content visible before scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, css-transforms

I have a weird issue with Chrome (it works as expected with Safari and Firefox). When a div exceeds a certain size, it is being cut off when transformed and scaled down (via a wheel event handler). Prior to the CSS transform applied, the content is visible when I scroll around. The container has overflow: auto set and again: it does work as expected in Safari.

What happens in the original app explained visually. This is what the screen looks like before any transforms: [image: before scale], then the image is scaled up to 10x size and redrawn (debounced). So far so good, I can scroll around and see all of the content being there. Then, the scale-down transform is applied and the result is missing content [image: is missing content]. What's even more strange: if you would scroll the viewport, parts of the image are re-appearing and disappearing again, depending how far one would scroll.

Don't mind the calculations in the JS snippet. They are incomplete and not correct as this is originally part of a React app and I stripped it down as much as possible in order to have a minimal and uncluttered example.

Anyone has an idea what is going on here? Any help would be highly appreciated as I have tried anything I could think of with no success.

```js
let transform = {
  scale: 1,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
};

document.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  if (!e.ctrlKey) {
    return;
  }

  e.preventDefault();

  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  const delta = Math.max(-2, Math.min(2, e.delta ?? e.wheelDelta));
  let scale = transform.scale + 0.025 * delta * transform.scale;

  const point = {
    x: e.pageX,
    y: e.pageY
  };

  const target = {
    x: (point.x - transform.x + container.scrollLeft) / transform.scale,
    y: (point.y - transform.y + container.scrollTop) / transform.scale
  }

  let x = -target.x * scale + point.x + container.scrollLeft;
  let y = -target.y * scale + point.y + container.scrollTop;

  transform = {
    scale,
    x,
    y
  };

  const app = document.getElementById("app");
  app.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(${scale})`;
}, {
  passive: false,
  capture: true
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #303030;
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

#app {
  width: 10000px;
  height: 10000px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  will-change: transform;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.frame {
  border: 400px solid rgb(4, 53, 69);
  width: 5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="app">
      <div class="frame"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug in Chromium. Filed a bug report, just in case anyone stumbles upon it before it’s fixed.